# Ascii Code Error in File Upload on Ubuntu Server

Tags: python, django, file, ubuntu, server

My project is running normally in my localhost but project is giving ascii code error in server.

```
Django output:
    'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0130' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This my_view;

```
def gallery(request):
    if admin_permission(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    showcase_list = Gallery.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        product_code = request.POST.get('product_code')
        photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
        small_photo = request.FILES.get('small_photo')
        # photo.name = 'photo'
        # small_photo.name = 'small_photo'
        code = request.POST.get('code')
        product = Products.objects.get(product_code=product_code)
        gallery = Gallery.objects.create(user=user, code=code, product=product, photo=photo, small_photo=small_photo,
                                         is_active=True)
        gallery.save()
    return render_to_response('Product/showcase/gallery.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Error page:

[image]

This is file upload error. If file name contains Turkish char, give that error. pls. help me...

Comment: some code would be useful. currently the question does not provide any details to debug this. full traceback and code which is causing exception will be very useful.

Comment: post the traceback as text (click "switch to copy-paste view").

Comment: related: [Django UnicodeEncodeError when displaying formset: ascii codec can't encode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32557468/4279)

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that your django process runs with C/POSIX locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=C python2
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir(u"\u0130")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0130' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To fix it, configure utf-8 locale e.g., `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`

Comment: yes, i have this error. I configured at locale, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KAYKISIZ: "doesn't work" is not very informative. Print `LANGUAGE`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LANG` envvars during an http request inside your django server.