# Django UnicodeEncodeError when displaying formset: ascii codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, django, unicode, modelform, formset

I am trying to simply display Model formset in django template. I get the following error

[image]

[image]

Here is what I am trying to display: the actual formset within a form

[image]

In the view.py, here is the related code snippet:

```
 #
 # create Address Model Form Set
 #
 AddressFormSet = modelformset_factory( Address, form=businessForms.AddressModelForm )

if request.method == 'GET':

    businessModelForm = businessForms.BusinessModelForm( instance = business )

    addressModelFormSet = AddressFormSet( queryset=Address.objects.filter(business__id=business.id) )
    #addressModelFormSet = AddressFormSet( )

    print addressModelFormSet.is_valid()  /* prints False */
    print addressModelFormSet.errors     /* prints [] empty list */

    return render(request, "business_profile.html", { 'businessModelForm' : businessModelForm,
                                                      'addressModelFormSet': addressModelFormSet })
```

I assume the validity of the form has nothing to do with this error since we check validity upon POST request, yet I could be wrong. No error list is shown though for the formset.

The AddressModelForm:

```
class AddressModelForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['street_address', 'address_line2', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code']
```

The model definition:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    phone_code = models.CharField(max_length = 3, default = '000')
    country_name_ar = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')

     #many-to-many fields
    currencies = models.ManyToManyField(Currency)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.country_name

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length = 93)
    city_name_ar = models.CharField(max_length = 93, default = '')
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s" % self.city_name) + "," + str(self.country)

class Address(models.Model):
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length = 500, default = '')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City) # country included implicitly in city
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = '')
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = '')

    def __str__(self):
        usStr = ("%s" % self.street_address) + "," + str(self.city) + "," + self.state + "," + self.zip_code
        nonUsStr = ("%s" % self.street_address) + "," + str(self.city)

        if self.state != '':
            return usStr
        else:
            return usStr
```

I am suspecting the fact that city model has city_name_ar which is Arabic field for city name ...

**UPDATE**
If I remove 'city' from AddressModelForm, or override the field to be CharField, I don't get this error, however, I get text field with city ID which is useless ...

Comment: I suspect that your database isn't storing stuff properly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you please explain? see my Update Above, when I remove city from the model form or override the field to show text field, it works fine

Comment: Open the database. Examine the table schema. Examine the byte sequence stored in that field.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using - 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: 2.7.9 I don't use 3.x not recommended yet by Django

Comment: Django supports 3.x as of release 1.5 - see the docs for exact version compatibility: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support . 2.x is fine, but you have to represent your objects a little differently. See my answer for details.

Comment: my bad. My info is stale, I should've upgraded python .... sigh...

Comment: Well, going from 2.x to 3.x is not a small change - if you have stuff working in 2.x it should be quicker to just do things the way 2.x expects.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 2.x. Under 2.x, models should either have a `__unicode__` method rather than or in addition to a `__str__` method, and each method should return the appropriate type (unicode for `__unicode__`, encoded bytes for `__str__`) or you should use the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator if you're on a sufficiently recent version of Django. If you're planning to stay on 2.x for the immediately future, I'd recommend just writing `__unicode__` methods and not bothering with the decorator since you're concatenating string representations and I'm not quite sure what it does with that.

Some relevant docs are:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods

Either way, you should avoid converting database values (which are passed around as Unicode object) without specifying the encoding. Generally it's easiest to just define a method that returns unicode, eg:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    # as above, except
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.country_name
```

Or:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Country(models.Model):
    # as above, except
    def __str__(self):
         return self.country_name
```

Similarly for your other models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.city_name + "," + unicode(self.country)
```

Or (untested, you might need to call `unicode(self.country)` here as well):

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class City(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name + "," + str(self.country)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that didn't fix it and now python.exe crashes and I get Access Violation exception (saw that in Visual Studio debugger). I used both options you gave with same result

Comment: That's weird. On a guess, you have bytes stored in your database that don't match the declared character set for the table. I am surprised that that can produce the error you're reporting but it's going to be impossible to debug remotely.